# Store Json string as MongoDB array in C#

Tags: mongodb, linq, asp.net-core, mongodb-query, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I want to store a JSON string in an array format in MongoDB.This is my C# code for storing notification into MongoDB, here the field "Event_meta" field sending as a JSON string format to MongoDB.

```
public async Task Handle(TaskPropertyUpdatedEvent eventmsg)
        {
        try
        {
            var meta = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventmsg.Event_meta);
            var notificationEvent = new Notifications()
            {
                Content = eventmsg.Content,
                Type = "TaskEvent",
                UserId = eventmsg.UpdatedById,
                EntityId = eventmsg.TaskId.ToString(),
                AddedDate = eventmsg.UpdatedDate,
                Active = true,
                ShowNotification = false,
                InternalEvent = true,
                UserName = eventmsg.UpdatedByName,
                Event_type = eventmsg.Event_type,
                Event_meta = meta

            };
            var result = await _eventRepository.AddEventAsync(notificationEvent);              
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }

    }
```

The "eventmsg.Event_meta" is a dynamic type."Event_meta" value storing in MongoDB as jsonstring.But i want store this as an Array format.

```
Event_meta :"[{"action":"added","propertyId":"e7b6df49-7ea5-422f-aa81- 
1d273d69da21"..."
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: So what if we cannot cast the Event_meta data to array format key-value pair ?

Comment: BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonArray>(json); this method returned bson array. or you can try add Dictionary<string,object>[] property and save to mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Event_meta field type into BsonDocument and deserialize as BsonDocument.
Or make your Notifications class as mapper class like [Mongo Doc](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/bson/mapping/)